# Lower case text on website displaying as upper case on Chrome browser only

Tags: google-chrome

first time poster so please go easy!

My Chrome browser is displaying some lower case text from my company's website as all upper case. It only seems to be doing it on chrome and on my computer - it displays properly (lower case) on Safari and on versions of Chrome used by my colleagues.

I'm hoping someone can help me - not sure if it is something website related or Chrome related.

Our website is built with Wordpress.

Thanks

Comment: Which is the website of your company?

Comment: https://thesoundreserve.com

Comment: I'm using 95.0.4638.69 (official build) (a 64 bit) and can't see upper case in any text except  "FREE & UNLIMITED", have you tried to check if you have some particular extension?

Comment: Thank you. I haven't looked at extensions - I'm a bit of a novice at this! I will try that next. Thank you for your help.